# create interval with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, cut

we can use cut to create interval data further to be label, also by utilize for loop

[image]

cut function

```
perform_vec <- perform[["Performance"]]
perf_labs <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
perfcut <- cut(perform_vec,breaks = c(0,25,49.99,69.99,84.99,94.99,101),right = F, labels = perf_labs)
perfcut_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(perform_vec, perfcut))
perfcut_df$perfcut <- factor(perfcut_df$perfcut, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), labels = c("D","C","B-","B","A-","A"))
```

resulting in the following:

[image]

i want to create it with for loop

Comment: If it works properly with `cut`, then why do you want to create it in a loop?

Comment: If you see the source code of `cut`, file `src/library/base/R/cut.R`, you will see that it calls a `C` function, `bincode` that can be found in `src/main/util.c`. Do you want more effective? Not in pure `R`.

Comment: Please do not use images for the input as it means that no one can use that input in their code without retyping it.  Please show it as R code by showing the output of `dput(x)` in the question where `x` is the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution #1 we count, in a loop, how many `breaks` each input value exceeds and then use that to index into `labels`.  Solution #2 does the same but using `outer` rather than a loop.  Solution #3 uses `cut`.

```
# input
x <- c(30, 50, 80)
breaks <- c(0,25,49.99,69.99,84.99,94.99,101)
labels <- c("D","C","B-","B","A-","A")

# solutions

# 1 - loop
lev <- 0 * x
for (b in breaks) lev <- lev + (x > b)
factor(labels[lev], levels = labels)
## [1] C  B- B 
## Levels: D C B- B A- A

# 2 - outer
factor(labels[rowSums(outer(x, breaks, `>`))], levels = labels)
## [1] C  B- B 
## Levels: D C B- B A- A

# 3 - cut
cut(x, breaks, labels)
## [1] C  B- B 
## Levels: D C B- B A- A
```